# How to: Use ejs without express

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm starting with node in general, and I'm attempting to do a site without express.
I would none the less want to use ejs to inject my html and this is where my problem is...
How do I attach the ejs.render(...) to the response?

PS: I know it might be a better option to use express, but I want to know how it works underneath before bridging it.

Something like:

```
var ejs = require("ejs");

function index (response, request, sequelize) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    test_data = "test data";
    response.end(ejs.render("./views/home.html",test_data));
}

exports.index = index;
```

But that works ^_^

Thanks!

Comment: "I want to know how it works underneath before bridging it." read express source then,how hard can it be?

Comment: not express... regular node

Comment: You want to learn how express does it.Seems logical to me to read in express source code how express does call ejs.Anyway seems also logical ejs is not going to care about the fact that your template is in another file, but takes a template string as an argument of render instead.

Comment: @npm, I want to know how node works before I jump into express.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all, You need install ejs -> $ npm install ejs --save

Simple example:

main.ejs:

```
<p> <%= exampleRenderEjs  %> </p>
```

server.ejs

```
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');

var htmlContent = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/main.ejs', 'utf8');

var htmlRenderized = ejs.render(htmlContent, {filename: 'main.ejs', exampleRenderEjs: 'Hello World!'});

console.log(htmlRenderized);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a project called [Consolidate.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js) which provides a common API for many template engines.  This ensures they can all be interchangeable.  If you want to render templates directly, you want to be compatible with this API.

Sample code from the Consolidate.js README:

```
var cons = require('consolidate');
cons.swig('views/page.html', { user: 'tobi' }, function(err, html){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(html); // Or write to your `res` object here
});
```

This sample is for Swig, but similar code works for EJS or any of the compatible engines.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without an interface?

Comment: Even though it was not the answer I was looking for, because I wanted specific to ejs, I believe this answer is better because it caters to any template engine.

Answer (score -3):

Example from some book:
**template.ejs**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      .entry_title { font-weight: bold; }
      .entry_date { font-style: italic; }
      .entry_body { margin-bottom: 1em; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <% entries.map(entry => { %>
      <div class="entry_title"><%= entry.title %></div>
      <div class="entry_date"><%= entry.date %></div>
      <div class="entry_body"><%= entry.body %></div>
    <% }); %>
  </body>
</html>


function blogPage(entries) {
    const values = { entries };
    const template = fs.readFileSync('./template.ejs', 'utf8');
    return ejs.render(template, values);
}


const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const entries = getEntries();
    const output = blogPage(entries);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(output);
    console.log('run server');
});
server.listen(8000);
```