# Render html in nodejs like in php

Tags: php, node.js, server-side-rendering

It seems like a simple question, but I can't find anything about it in google or stackoverflow. Probably I haven't found the right keywords.

In php you can write something like this

example.php

```
<?php
//a bunch of sloppy logic, or maybe some includes but for this I'll just define the variables below...
  $title = "Word to your mother";
  $heading = "Too legit";
  $paragraph = "Extensive research has shown that people's taste in music stops changing once they are forced to earn a living. Maybe that's when they learn how dumb the lyrics really are or maybe they don't have time to waste on things that no longer matter...";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title><?=$title?></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1><?=$heading?></h1>
  <p><?=$paragraph?></p>
  <h2>Counting</h2>
  <?php
    for($x=1;$x<=10;$x++){
  ?>
    <p><?=$x?></p>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Is there some equivalent of this in nodejs?**

The broader question has something to do with serving dynamic content from a nodejs server that the browser sees as static. Solutions that require any kind of JavaScript on the client side will not work for me.

I saw ejs and vue but they both have something like `<script src='source.js'>` on the DOM which is exactly what I don't want and can't have.

If you think this is a duplicate, please say in the comments and give me a chance to clarify before marking it as a duplicate.

**Clarification/Update:**

The term "template" is probably a negative keyword for the functionality I'm trying to describe. In the php example above I could nest a html element inside of an if statement or loop while keeping the server markup inline.
There's another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602560/write-nodejs-web-application-like-php) where the question basically asked the same thing but the answer is not remotely satisfactory.

Comment: So you don't want styles or interactivity on the page? Then why not hardcode it?

Comment: I want a dynamic page served without javascript. I can't hand write ever combination of html and content for whatever a user may do. Php makes it really easy, and I thought for sure that some similar functionality would exist in nodejs, even if only as a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you to Josan and Austin. I read ejs.co and the docs and couldn't find what I'm talking about on their page. Josan in his comment described that it could follow the looping and conditional but I couldn't understand how. There weren't any examples of what I included below.

Eventually I came across [How to: Use ejs without express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901787/how-to-use-ejs-without-express) which simply spits the rendering to console. Here is the same php example I had in the original question, but done completely in node.js in the most minimal way possible, I think.

server.js

```
const http = require('http');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');

const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
var htmlContent = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/main.ejs', 'utf8');
var htmlRenderized = ejs.render(htmlContent, {filename: 'example.ejs'});

  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.end(htmlRenderized);
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

example.ejs:

```
<%
  var title = "Word to your mother";
  var heading = "Too legit";
  var paragraph = "Extensive research has shown that people's taste in music stops changing once they are forced to earn a living. Maybe that's when they learn how dumb the lyrics really are or maybe they don't have time to waste on things that no longer matter...";
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title><%=title%></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1><%=heading%></h1>
  <p><%=paragraph%></p>
  <h2>Counting</h2>
  <%
    for(x=1;x<=10;x++){
  %>
    <p><%=x%></p>
  <%
    }
  %>
 </body>
</html>
```

Granted, the values for title, heading and paragraph in the `ejs.render` method if included in the object being passed, which is the example you usually get to see when looking up examples for ejs.

Answer (score 3):

Using Express, you can use a template engine such as EJS to serve static content from the sever.

> At runtime, the template engine replaces variables in a template file with actual values, and transforms the template into an HTML file sent to the client.

If you have never used Express, you can read about it here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I specifically researched ejs before posting the question and specifically mentioned it as something that doesn't seem to work. I see the link you included, where content can be fed at render through a json style string into a fixed template. Is there nothing less restrictive?

Comment: EJS allows you to not only pass data from the sever to the template, but you can also run other JavaScript functions like a `for` loop. Have a look at their docs: ejs.co

Answer (score 1):

[PugJS](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)

[Integrating PugJS wit Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)

PugJS can be integrated quickly into an Express app, rendered server-side into HTML and served to the client without any requirements for client-side JS dependencies.